# Different term used to mention an Interfaces special properties in java?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I am working in java from some time. I know their are some thing knows as interface in java. While reading about them I come to know their is marker interface. Recently when i started reading about java 8  I come to know about an other interface Functional  Interface.

I am just wondering what are the different kind of Interfaces available in java?

Comment: I mean, there's not really anything _special_ about those.  They're just names for interfaces that have a couple handy properties.

Comment: I know these make things better to communicate when we say i have created functional interface other designer able to understand what I m talking about

Comment: That is why i wanted to know. Down voter please explain why down voted?

Comment: A functional interface is one which can be used to define a function, and a marker interface does nothing but "mark" the class. There is no glossary of these terms really.

Comment: I know about them,  I wanted to understand is their any thing other then these two term exist related to interface properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standard Interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860977/standard-interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

The Java language specification doesn't itself define the term marker interface and the term has been coined by authors, developers and designers. One common question asked is if we can create a marker interface or not and the answer is yes because of following reason:

We can't create marker interface similar to Serializable or Cloneable but we can simulate the functionality by writing extra code around the custom marker interface.

An empty interface is known as tag or marker interface. For example Serializable, EventListener, Remote(java.rmi.Remote) are tag interfaces. These interfaces do not have any field and methods in it. 
Read more here: http://beginnersbook.com/2016/03/tag-or-marker-interfaces-in-java/

Functional Interface is the new addition in Java 8, An interface with exactly one abstract method is called Functional Interface. Read more [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2763/java-8-functional-interfaces).

There are no other types of Interfaces in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There's no special meaning for each.

`Marker interface` is kind of "[design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)", you attach a label/tag to a set of objects in order to indicates that they have something in common, they're OK for some kind of process or operations. `Serializable` is a typical example, it **marks** objects that they can be serialized/deserialized.

On the other hand for `FunctionalInterface`, it's just an `interface` with restriction that can only have one abstract method, and thus represents a single function contract. Java 8 add `lambda expression` for `functional programming`, for `FP` we need to pass `function` back and forth so often. Say we have an interface like:

```
public interface StringTrasformer {
    String transform(Object obj);
}
```

Traditionally we can only create instance of asynchronous class like:

```
someObj.doTransform(new StringTransformer() {
    @Override
    public String transform(Object object) {
        return "result";
    }
});
```

But there's only one method to be implemented, so it's no need to make code so verbose, with `lambda expression` it could be as short as:

```
abc.doTransform(object -> "result");
```

Annotation `FunctionalInterface` is used for compiler to check whether the interface you have annotated is a valid one. Even functional interface is for `lambda expressions`, `method references`and `constructor references`, but nothing prevents you to use it the traditional way. Because essentially it is just an normal interface.